# Allowing image to overflow the parent div but need to push content below down

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[the design i'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z2UC.png)

Hi there, First time posting here :)

Im stuck! and have been for hours lol..

I want to add an image under some text within a div which will overflow down the page.  However, the image is running under my footer etc and not pushing it down.  I've been playing around with position:relative on the div & position:absolute on the footer etc but I just cant seem to get it working!

I've attached my code. the image is random but it's similar size to the one I'm using locally.

Any help would be hugely appreciated

```css
/* My Work page */

.wallpaper {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: var(--peach);
  position: relative;
}

.my-work-text {
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 30%; */
  /* left: 50%; */
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -100%); */
  color: var(--black);
  font-family: "playfair display";
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 20%;
}

.my-work-screenshot {
  margin: auto;
}


/* FOOTER */

footer {
  /* margin-top: 100px; */
  color: #fff;
  background-color: var(--black);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

footer>h5 {
  padding: 8px;
}

footer>p {
  line-height: 0.4rem;
}

footer>hr {
  margin: 30px 0 20px 0;
}

footer>ul {
  list-style: none;
}

footer>ul>li>a,
a:link,
a:hover,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--white);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- MAIN TEXT & BG -->
<section>
  <div class="wallpaper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="my-work-text">
        <h2>Bryan Johnston Cichlids</h2>
        <p>Bryan is a specialist aquarium fish seller and was looking for site to showcase his business. I provided Bryan with a complete service from design, functionality & development</p>
      </div>

      <div class="my-work-screenshot container">
        <img src="https://www.xda-developers.com/files/2018/04/longshot-example.png" class="img-fluid shadow" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>




<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer>
  <h5>BLOXY WEB DESIGN & DEVELOPMENT</h5>
  <p>Professional website designer and developer</p>
  <p>Tel: 07806 615231</p>
  <p>Email:stuart@sjbloxham.co.uk</p>

  <hr />
  <ul .footer-links>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Get in touch</a></li>
  </ul>
  <p>© Copyright Bloxy Web Design & Development</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: problem one: don't use `position: absolute` for your footer.

Comment: please add snippet and tell me more about that image you want add under text. please. so I can understand your problem

Comment: hey think i updated the snippet correctly.  sorry, I'm new to this.  the image is a long screenshot of another site I designed. i want the entire image to show.  hope this helps, thanks!

Comment: you can see where the footer overlaps the image.  I want this footer to be pused to the bottom and the image to fill the page

Comment: When you say you want the footer to be pushed to the bottom, do you mean that it is to be fixed to the bottom of the viewport (i.e. always visible?) or that it comes right at the end of the other content so you don't see it until you scroll down? Either way I don't understand why you have given it position absolute;

Comment: No I want it to be at the bottom of the content like a normal footer.  Yeah please ignore the position:absolute bit.. I added this when I was reading bits on forums etc.  I just want the footer to be at the bottom of the page without the image just continuing over it.

Answer (score 1):

1.If you want have normal footer like most websites, you must use `position: relative` for `footer`, also if you don't add `position` to your `footer` tag it will be `relative` by default.

2.If your page content are less than monitor, footer not fixing at the bottom of page. If you want add more content later like the picture, 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z2UC.png' just use `position: relative` or remove `position` attribute from footer css.

3. If you have few content and footer not pushing at the bottom, better use `position: fixed` and add `bottom:0` and `left:0` , So footer can understand where to be fixed. and add `z-index: 555` so It's be placed over other contents.
4. when you want use `position: absolute` you must first make it's parent to `position: relative` so it can understand where to be placed of his parent. Also in absolute you have to use `left: "number"` and add `top: "number"`. in `absolute` and `fixed` you must add least one point in each AXIS , in Axis X: left or right, in Axis Y: top or bottom. if you don't add relative to parent of absolute, it will be absolute of the whole page.

Comment: thank you Amir,  your answer is much appreciated :)